# In Java is there a way to define enum of type char

Tags: java, enums

I was wondering if we can have enaum values of type char? 
I would like to do something like this:

```
public enum Enum    {char X, char Y};
...
Enum a=Enum.X
if (a=='X')
{// do something}
```

**without calling any extra function to convert enum to char** ( as I want it to be char already). Is there a way to do so?

- In fact this way I am trying to define a restricted variable of type char which only accepts one of two char values 'X' or 'Y'. So that if we give anything else such as 'z', the compiler complains.

Comment: Why does it have to be a `char`? Why can it not just stay a standard `enum`?

Comment: `enum`s are Object , not `char`s.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No.

But the conversion method isn't very hard, at all.

```
public enum SomeChar {
    X('X'), Y('Y');

    public char asChar() {
        return asChar;
    }

    private final char asChar;

    SomeChar(char asChar) {
        this.asChar = asChar;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
if (a.asChar() == 'X') { ... }
```

If you don't like having the asChar field/constructor, you can even implement the getter as `return name().charAt(0)`.

If you're using [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/), this becomes even easier:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
public enum SomeChar {
    X('X'), Y('Y');
    private final char asChar;
}

if (a.getAsChar() == 'X') { ...
```

---

Btw, an enum named `Enum` would be confusing, since most people will see `Enum` in the source and assume it's `java.lang.Enum`. In general, shadowing a commonly used/imported class name is dangerous, and classes don't get more commonly imported than `java.lang.*` (which is always imported).

Comment: Checkout the: [**Enum tutorial**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) page.